# Excel: How to find text in col B and use data validation list in col C – automatic

Tags: excel, validation

I have a list in column C with data validation (CAR, FOOD, ANIMAL). In column B, there are hundreds of lines, with some text. But I know for example that (BMW,VOLVO,OPEL,KIA) often is written in col B. Those I want to label as CAR. I don’t want to make I manually so how can I do it automatic, with a rule?

Comment: Is BMW, VOLVO, OPEL, etc. the only word in column B? And does it occur multiple times? If both is true, you need to use a table that assigns each unique term to a category - and then use a `VLOOKUP` formula in column C that looks up column B in this table.

Comment: Column B can have other words like CAT, DOG, STAR, MUSIC, LOVE, (but they are not known). BMW,VOLVO, OPEL occur multiple times and are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a support table that has all the words you're aware of. Then you can lookup this table with a VLOOKUP formula. In the following example I placed this table in columns E&F:

[image]

I used the following formula in C2:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,E:F,2,0),"Unknown category")
```

Comment: If the table is more complicated, i.e. column B can have more then one word. Example if B8 is "Volvo gear" - label it as "CAR", and B9 is "Dog food" - label as "Animal". How to do that?

Comment: You can use a formula to extract the first word, `=IFERROR(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1),B2)` - and then apply the VLOOKUP to this result.